# Excessive number of TaskCanceledExceptions

Tags: service, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I've just started looking at Service Fabric, and was hoping someone could help with a problem I am having.

We have started noticing an excessive number of TaskCanceledExceptions being thrown back to RunAsync. This seems to be caused by Service Fabric setting the cancellation token which was passed into RunAsync.

I understand there are legitimate reasons for Service Fabric setting the token, like if the service is restarted, or the primary is demoted, but we are seeing hundreds of thousands in some months (and hardly any in others).

My questions are:

- What scenarios could cause the setting of large numbers of cancellation tokens?
- SF must log the reason it cancelled a given token. Where does Service Fabric log this kind of information?

Comment: Might be a service that is in a crash/recover loop. In that case the number of failures should keep up with the number of cancellations. The cause of the failures is then the reason for cancelling the token.It might also be the case that, for example due to placement constraints, SF is continuously trying to place / start the service somewhere and that fails. The cancellations are merely the symptom of an underlying problem.

Comment: Sounds good - I'll investigate.
But how can I tell why SF is performing the cancellations? Does it log this information somewhere?